# How likely are you to be stressed in academia?

Tags: emotional-responses, work-life-balance, working-time

So a little context. I'm a second year masters student in theoretical physics and last year I almost had a burnout. I mean that I had symptoms of burnout but it was not severe enough to be an actual burnout (luckily). What stressed me out most was the frequent deadlines. The material also got harder compared to my bachelor which contributed as well. After taking it easy for a while now and talking to a psychologist to help cope with stress I'm feeling much better. I would rather not have this experience another time or even worse. So, since a lot of theoretical physicists go into academia my question is how likely are you to be stressed in academia? Or more specifically

1. How likely are you to be stressed in academia? Do you know examples of people who are very stressed/not stressed at all?
2. If it is stressful, is it possible to reduce your workload? Or is it possible to manage this stress?

Comment: +1 I'm sure the stress level of any person in Academia depends on individual factors, but they are unlikely to be completely idiosyncratic. So it would be interesting to know what these factors are. I'm sure research has been done on stress-levels and coping mechanisms across professions, perhaps even specifically among academics. This would be interesting as well.

Comment: The health implications of stress significantly depend on your mental attitude to stress. See this [very insightful TED talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/kelly_mcgonigal_how_to_make_stress_your_friend?language=de).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A majority of the expectations tend to be self-imposed.

While there are some things you're made to do by others, most deadlines etc come from your own choices. Do you agree to referee that paper? Do you want to submit to that conference? Do you agree to give that talk?

2. There is no "having done enough".

There is always something more that you could do. There will be almost certainly peers who get much, much more done than you (or at least appear to do). Research is never finished. The academic job market is very tight, so until you have tenure, there is always this question of "could doing this extra thing be the decisive factor in whether or not I get a job"?

3. Deadlines tend to be on a medium time scale.

Unless you are eg a postdoc with a micromanaging team lead, you will be rather flexible in the short term. Teaching aside, things are of the "do this this week/month", nor "this day".

4. There does seem to be a widespread culture of celebrating stress.

While relaxed academics exist, in my experience most academics tend to convey an aura of constant low-level stress. Of those, many seem to enjoy this. Admitting to be overwhelmed is very much acceptable, but I suspect that the stress can be infectious for some people.

Comment: This was actually really helpful! Point 1 seems to imply that you have at least some control over it. Point 3&4 give a nice quantification. I will wait a bit for other responses but I think I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

One particular feature of academe (I'm in math in the U.S.) that seems very unfortunate to me is that there is *not* a tradition of giving positive feedback to other people. And, in all the university administrations I've observed, there is more consistent effort exerted in "explaining" why there's just no money for raises... Never cost-of-living, and "merit" is 2%?!? When there are economic problems, salaries can get cut, but in economic good times, they'll not get comparable boosts.

We are in a situation where "everyone is above average", but somehow we're all still led to feel that we are on the edge of failure, especially with the trend in recent decades of appraisal of much shorter-term pictures of one's work, as opposed to "lifetime achievement", and as opposed to long-term projects.

The popularity of "performance appraisal software" in administrations is yet another mechanism that manifestly over-simplifies "good behavior" on the part of faculty.

Unless one is able to somehow ignore such stuff, it is at least annoying... and chronic annoyance is stress, and has a cognitive load.

Comment: "especially with the trend in recent decades of appraisal of much shorter-term pictures of one's work, as opposed to "lifetime achievement", and as opposed to long-term projects." I've heard this expressed too by older mathematicians. Everyone acknowledges that "academia has changed." It is not uncommon nowadays to have several papers straight out of grad school. I once lamented to a mathematician that you must have at least 2 published papers out of grad school to get a postdoc. He responded, "Look at this Fields medalist. How many papers did he/she have out of grad school?"

Answer (score 0):

It is stressful but it comes with rewards.  The key thing is to assess if these rewards - they are not necessarily monetary but rather as Feynman stated just “the pleasure of finding things out” - are enough for *you* to compensate for the long hours and the actual stresses.

Personally I find I was well prepared for the challenges of research but not so well prepared to confront the naked stupidity and populism of some people I work with.

I deal with this by *increasing* my workload, giving me an out to avoid interactions with the people I like least.  This ability to basically isolate oneself from the local sh!tstorms and work pretty much always with people I like is probably the most important way I manage my stressors (not so easy for students or junior faculty though).